# how to get below xml data by jaxb

Tags: jaxb

I have below xml file, anyone can tell me how to use jaxb to get the data from this xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entity>
    <hello>test123</hello>
    <field name="user-template-07">sun, jerry</field>
    <field name="id">179339</field>
</entity>
```

There are two  elements, how to distinguish and get value 'sun , jerry' and 179339 ?

Comment: What do you want your object model to look like?

Comment: Actually I know how to get the value if the xml looks like below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entity>
    <hello>test123</hello>
    <field1>sun, jerry</field1>
    <field2>179339</field2>
</entity>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the root class (i.e. `Entity`) you are going to have a property like the following:

```
@XmlElement(name="field")
private List<Field> fields;
```

And your `Field` class will look like:

```
@XmlAcessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Field {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Doughan, It works now! However I use another solution by with EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy). also post by you :) http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html#comment-form